# XMLHttpRequest: Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, accesscontrolexception

We have media that lives on a server that we have no control over its configuration. We use OAuth1.0 to request permission using a secret key and customer key.

Once we receive a response with the OAuth signature and other url parameters that are returned with the response. We pass the these url parameters to a template that contains a hidden form. The form gets populated with the various parameters and then the form is submitted. The form's post action points to the media endpoint that lives on the remote server and the requested media is supposed to come back in the response.

The problem is that both Chrome and Safari report the issue that

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load www.example.com. Origin www.example.com is
>   not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

www.example.com is the remote server.

**In Chrome, the media comes back even though this error is there.
In Safari, it throws the error and does not allow me to see the media.**

Any advice on how to go about this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar It is not entirely the same because the issue I am facing is in safari and not in Chrome. It is not a general question about CORS.

Comment: It depends, do you want it to work for everyone or just for you? There is an option to disable cross-origin restrictions in Safari if you just need it to work for you.